# Nodejs: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.stringify (native)

Tags: node.js, node-streams

When I call following function to write the array object to a file, it works  properly with normal size of array

```
function stringifyArrayToFile(array, file) {
    const transform = new stream.Transform({
        objectMode: true
    })
    transform._hasWritten = false
    transform._transform = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {
        if (!this._hasWritten) {
            this._hasWritten = true;
            this.push('[' + JSON.stringify(chunk) + '\n')
        } else {
            this.push(',' + JSON.stringify(chunk) + '\n')
        }
        callback()
    }
    transform._flush = function (callback) {
        this.push(']')
        callback()
    }

    const writeable = fs.createWriteStream(file).setDefaultEncoding("utf-8")
    array.toStream().pipe(transform).pipe(writeable)
}
```

But I will get following error when there are around 5000 elements in array:

```
this.push('[' + JSON.stringify(chunk) + '\n')
                     ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.stringify (native)
```

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code but i tried code bellow which seems to work just fine.

Can you make sure that `this._hasWritten` is set to true for all chunks except for the first one by adding `console.log(this._hasWritten);` just above `if (!this._hasWritten) {`

This is my code, give it a try:

```
function stringifyArrayToFile(array, file) {

    var writeable = fs.createWriteStream(file).setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");

    writeable.write('[\n');

    !function write() {
        var val = array.pop();
        if (!val)
            return writeable.end(']');

        if (!writeable.write(JSON.stringify(val) + ',\n')) {
            writeable.once('drain', write);
        } else {
            process.nextTick(write);
        }
    }();

}
```

Comment: thank you for the alternative, but I got same error:  

if (!writeable.write(JSON.stringify(val) + ',\n')) {
                                  ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: That's strange, I tested it with 6000 objects in an array without any issue. Aren't you by any chance calling the  stringifyArrayToFile function multiple times? In some loop or something? You may want to add the code where you use the function so we can see some context. Aren't you running out of available RAM?

Comment: How big is each chunk or how big is each of the objects in the array? If there are huge objects then it could be the reason for the error.

Comment: sorry, the code was correct, there was bug in other function... the error message was misleading...